# Crystal Reports sales report showing all dates even when not existing

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have been searching for answers on this for a couple of days but not found any useful results.

A bit of the backstory:

I have about ~20k items that i'm trying to do a lifetime sales history report on.Some items have history from 1/1/2005. Sales are only noted on dates they occur.

Trying to graph first lifetime of sales history by days, first 6mo of sales, and last 30 days of sales. I don't have permission to add a temp table, so i am working with importing an excel file. (and for some reason you can't right-outer-join it to invoice date. im guessing because it's external?)

My problem is that there HAS to be a simple way to tell crystal to include/print missing dates without a lookup table. I've already got the start and end dates passed to parameters.

Isn't there a way to dynamically generate missing dates between {?PM-Start} to {?PM-End}? Using a lookup table to check if all days from 1/1/2005-currentdate match is 90,000,000,000 extra bloops to check.

That would take hours to run. It should be able to grab minumum(sale_date), and maximum(sale_date) and plop a record for each day whether it exists in the DB or not. (How is this not already a basic function?)

Or am I just missing something super simple?

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there any way to dynamically generate missing dates between `{?PM-Start}` to `{?PM-End}`? Using a lookup table to check if all days from 1/1/2005-currentdate match is 90,000,000,000 extra bloops to check.

By using a query like below you can generate a calendar view to fill missing date:

```
;with years(yyyy) as (
    select 2005
    union all
    select yyyy + 1
    from years
    where yyyy < datepart(year, getdate())
), months(mm) as (
    select 1
    union all
    select mm + 1
    from months
    where mm < 12
), allDays(dd) as (
    select 1
    union all 
    select dd + 1
    from allDays
    where dd < 31
), calendar as (
    select --datefromparts(y.yyyy, m.mm, d.dd) [date]
         cast(cast(y.yyyy as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(m.mm as varchar(2))+'-'+cast(d.dd as varchar(2)) as date) [date]
    from allDays d
    cross join
        months m
    cross join
        years y
    where isdate(cast(y.yyyy as varchar(4))+ '/'+cast(m.mm as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(d.dd as varchar(2))) <> 0
)
select *
from calendar;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/6110)

Comment: That did it. I'm in tears. what a headache. Thank you so much!

Comment: How would i make this string a DateValue before crystal recognizes it as a strin (for datetime joins) without blowing up your pretty code? The SQL side of reporting is still a bit over my head.

Comment: You can use a `left join` like this: `select calendar.[date], sum(salecount) total from calendar left join sales on calendar.[date]=sales.[date] group by calendar.[date];` ;).